# Fatal Exception: android.widget.TextView.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState

Tags: android, android-viewpager, stack-overflow

My project gets the following error for many times.
But the error does not show the source class.

This is one of the errors I get:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8192KB
       at android.widget.TextView.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(TextView.java:8240)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:8303)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:8303)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:8303)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:8303)
       at android.view.View.onAttachedToWindow(View.java:20750)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.onAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:5880)
       at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21308)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4239)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4246)
       at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21286)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4239)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4246)
       at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21286)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4239)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4246)
       at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21286)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4239)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:6001)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5777)....
```

I checked the view pager classes is there anything wrong with that class?

```
public class VPClass extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public VPTutorialClass(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_tutorial, container,false);

        TextView textViewTutorial = view.findViewById(R.id.item_text_view_tutorial);
       
      textViewTutorial.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(tutorialMessages[position]));
        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view, 0);
        return view;

    }  
  ...
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a `view` to the `container` like this `container.addView(view);`

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_tutorial, container, false);
    TextView textViewTutorial = view.findViewById(R.id.item_text_view_tutorial);

    ...
    ...
    
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}
```